# Why Oracle ignores USE_NL_WITH_INDEX hint?

Tags: oracle, abap, opensql

having sql for a big table join (232mln records) with GTT by index. explanation looks like below:

```
4 NESTED LOOPS
  ( Estim. Costs = 439,300 , Estim. #Rows = 548,275 )
  Estim. CPU-Costs = 3,642,574,678 Estim. IO-Costs = 438,956

    1 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN ZTRM_REXP_PRESEL~0
      ( Estim. Costs = 336 , Estim. #Rows = 548,275 )
      Estim. CPU-Costs = 3,432,714 Estim. IO-Costs = 336
    3 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED TEXT_REXP_ITEM
      ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
      Estim. CPU-Costs = 6,637 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
      Filter Predicates

        2 INDEX RANGE SCAN TEXT_REXP_ITEM~Y01
          ( Estim. Costs = 1 , Estim. #Rows = 1 )
          Search Columns: 3
          Estim. CPU-Costs = 4,523 Estim. IO-Costs = 1
          Access Predicates
```

it shows wrong estimations because of GTT usage. the goal is to make Nested loop for index (2) and gtt (1) first and only then make access to a table itself (3). for some reason, hint USE_NL_WITH_INDEX("TEXT_REXP_ITEM" "TEXT_REXP_ITEM~Y01") is simply being ignored. any ideas why?

(1) consists of

```
EXPOSURE_ID
VERSION
```

(2) consists of

```
Column Name                     #Distinct

MANDT                                            1
ZZHEAD_EXPOSURE_ID                         251,454
ZZHEAD_VERSION                               3,217
ZZHEAD_ATTRIBUTE_DH01                        1,691
EXT_ITEM_ID                                    823
ZZHEAD_ATTRIBUTE_LH01                            3
ZZHEAD_RELEASE_STATE                             1
```

(1) and (2) are joined by exposure_id and version fields

text explanation

```
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |                    |   548K|   135M|   439K  (1)| 00:00:18 |
|   4 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | ZTRM_REXP_PRESEL~0 |   548K|    16M|   336   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TEXT_REXP_ITEM     |     1 |   228 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TEXT_REXP_ITEM~Y01 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

thank you

Comment: Just going back to your subject line.  Why is it ignoring a hint?  Because hints are just that - hints.  They are not commands.  There are many many reasons a hint may be ignored.  It would be impossible to say any more without seeng the actual query and the ddl for _all_ of the tables involved, and their indexes.

Comment: @EdStevens - hints **are** commands! The optimizer must obey them if it's _possible_ to do so. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D316D545-89E2-4D54-977F-FC97815CD62E) _The optimizer uses these hints to choose an execution plan for the statement, unless some condition exists that prevents the optimizer from doing so._

Comment: show your full query in OpenSQL and structures of all the tables involved

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer *is* obeying the hint. As [the docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-F630F1F6-E5FC-448E-91DC-9A4D953C1114):

> The USE_NL_WITH_INDEX hint instructs the optimizer to join the
>   specified table to another row source with a nested loops join using
>   the specified table as the inner table

In a nested loop, the outer table is the first one accessed. The inner table is the second.

So the plan uses `ZTRM_REXP_PRESEL~0` as the outer table. And `TEXT_REXP_ITEM` as the inner table. Which is exactly what you've asked for!

Constructing a similar example and using Oracle Database 19c's hint reporting mechanism shows the hint is followed:

```
create table t1 (
  c1 int
);
create table t2 (
  c1 int, c2 varchar2(100)
);

create index i1
  on t1 ( c1 );

create index i2
  on t2 ( c1 );

insert into t1 values ( 1, 'stuff' );

insert into t2
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 1000
)
  select x, rpad ( 'stuff', 100, 'f' ) 
  from   rws;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 't1' ) ;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 't2' ) ;

set serveroutput off
select /*+ USE_NL_WITH_INDEX ( T2 I2 ) */* 
from   t1
join   t2
on     t1.c1 = t2.c1;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'BASIC LAST +HINT_REPORT'));

Plan hash value: 3271411982                                                    

---------------------------------------------                                  
| Id  | Operation                    | Name |                                  
---------------------------------------------                                  
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |                                  
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |      |                                  
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |      |                                  
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | I1   |                                  
|   4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I2   |                                  
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2   |                                  
---------------------------------------------                                  

Hint Report (identified by operation id / Query Block Name / Object Alias):    
Total hints for statement: 1                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    

   4 -  SEL$58A6D7F6 / T2@SEL$1                                                
           -  USE_NL_WITH_INDEX ( T2 I2 )
```

Comment: yes, your plan is what i'm trying to achieve. but unfortunately, optimiser reads index and then reads table, but i was expecting it to have a nested loops of outer table with Y01 index first. and yes, i'm on Oracle 12.1

Comment: You mean a "double nested loop" join? Why do you specifically want that plan? You mentioned row estimates are an issue; try and fix this instead of using hints. Session specific stats for GTTs came in 12.1; these may help

Comment: in SAP stats are transaction specific i'm afraid and we have no direct control over it. Double NL is prefered as first NL with index should decrease drastically number of rows. Now selection starts without consideration of GTT join (GTT consists of keys actually that are also present in index). So it takes 548K records from index, reads then table for other filters and only after joins with GTT which has 54k records. So by double NL i would expecting to decrease initial selection 10 times.